# Progress bar only starts after first transition: Jquery Cycle2

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-cycle2

I use the jQuery Cycle2 script for a slideshow with progress bar. I am using jQuery v1.12.4.

The progress bar only starts working after the a slide transition. The first slide will show no progression in the bar, but will transition to the next slide. After this transition the progress bar starts working. It keeps working in all cases: navigating to previous or next, pause on hover, navigating with thumbnails etc.

The Cycle2 script is loaded after the footer. The script file calling the cycle function is loaded after that.

The code I use for the progress bar is pretty much directly taken from the example:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var slideshow = jQuery('.cycle-slider').cycle();
        var progress = jQuery('#progress');

        slideshow.on( 'cycle-initialized cycle-before', function( e, opts ) {
        progress.stop(true).css( 'width', 0 );
        });

        slideshow.on( 'cycle-initialized cycle-after', function( e, opts ) {
        if ( ! slideshow.is('.cycle-paused') )
            progress.animate({ width: '100%' }, opts.timeout, 'linear' );
        });

        slideshow.on( 'cycle-paused', function( e, opts ) {
         progress.stop(); 
        });

        slideshow.on( 'cycle-resumed', function( e, opts, timeoutRemaining ) {
        progress.animate({ width: '100%' }, timeoutRemaining, 'linear' );
        });

        });
```

The example show the progress bar starting immediately.

What could cause the progress bar to only start after a transition?

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: I solved it by calling 'pause' and then 'resume' immediately after. That way the progress bar is triggered on the first run. Maybe not optimal, but it works.